# Outer function R - maintain coordinate subtraction

Tags: r

I have two matrices, call them A (n x 2) and B (q x 2). I'd like to get an n x q x 2 array C, such that C[1,5,] represents the difference between the first row of A and the fifth row of B, taking the subtraction of the first element in the first row of A with the first element in the fifth row of B and the second element similarly subtracted.

I'm trying to perform this function via the `outer` function, but it also gives me the "non-diagonal" subtractions; i.e. it will also subtract A[1,1] - B[5,2] and A[1,2] - B[5,1] which I am not interested in. Does anyone have a fast, easy way to do this?

Current code

```
>diffs <- outer(A,B,FUN ='-')
>diffs[1,,5,]
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] **-0.3808701** 0.7591052
[2,]  0.2629293 **1.4029046**
```

I've added the stars to indicate what I actually want.

Thanks for any help in advance

(EDIT)
Here's a simpler case for illustrative purposes

```
> A <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
> B <- matrix(4:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
> A
         [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
> B
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    7
[2,]    5    8
[3,]    6    9

>diffs <- outer(A,B,FUN ='-')
>diffs[1,,3,] == (A[1,] - B[3,])
        [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE

>diffs[1,,3,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -5   -8
[2,]    0   -3
```

Comment: "Can you post a snippet of data so that people can test?" – copied from the comments of your previous question. We _really_ like [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s here

Comment: @AkselA Let me know if you think the edit is sufficient

Comment: Do you simply want to extract the diagonal, i.e. `diag(diffs[1,,3,])`?

Comment: Yes, but for all combinations of the first and third coordinate. Ideally there'd be some manipulation of the function (or use of some other function I'm currently unfamiliar with) that would only involve subtraction of the pertinent coordinates.

Comment: Hmm. Something like this `diag(outer(A[1,], B[3,], FUN='-'))`?

Comment: Like I said I need it for all the combinations of the first and third index. 
E.g. diag(outer(A[1,], B[1,], FUN='-')),diag(outer(A[1,], B[2,], FUN='-')), diag(outer(A[1,], B[3,], FUN='-')) , diag(outer(A[2,], B[1,], FUN='-')),... I'd prefer not to have to use a for loop though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before worrying about the shape of the output I think we should make sure we're getting the correct values.

```
A <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5, ncol=2)
B <- matrix(4:9, nrow=3, ncol=2)

# long-winded method
dia_long <- c(
c(A[1,] - B[1,]),
c(A[1,] - B[2,]),
c(A[1,] - B[3,]),
c(A[2,] - B[1,]),
c(A[2,] - B[2,]),
c(A[2,] - B[3,]),
c(A[3,] - B[1,]),
c(A[3,] - B[2,]),
c(A[3,] - B[3,]),
c(A[4,] - B[1,]),
c(A[4,] - B[2,]),
c(A[4,] - B[3,]),
c(A[5,] - B[1,]),
c(A[5,] - B[2,]),
c(A[5,] - B[3,]))

# loop method
comb <- expand.grid(1:nrow(A), 1:nrow(B))
dia_loop <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(comb)) {
    dia_loop[[i]] <- A[comb[i, 1], ] - B[comb[i, 2], ]
}
dia_loop <- unlist(dia_loop)

# outer/apply method
dia_outer <- apply(outer(A, B, FUN='-'), c(3, 1), diag)

# they all return the same values
all.identical <- function(l) {
    all(sapply(2:length(l), FUN=function(x) identical(l[1], l[x])))
}

all.identical(lapply(list(dia_long, dia_loop, dia_outer), sort))
# TRUE

table(dia_long)
# dia_long
# -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
#  1  2  4  5  6  5  4  2  1
```

Are these the values you are looking for?

Comment: Not quite this does get the right values, but converting it to an array doesn't retain it's sense - I came up with a solution that works for my purposes - posted it below if you're curious

Comment: I converted it to that shape because that was the shape you used in your example (`diag(outer(A[1,], B[1,], FUN='-')); diag(outer(A[1,], B[2,], FUN='-'))`...). I can't read minds, you know.

Comment: Ah. I appreciate your attention and I'm sorry my code wasn't clear... for the record I did state I was looking for an n x q x 2 array in the first line of my question.

Comment: @Adam: Are you sure the values are correct? do `table(diffs)` and compare with my results. They don't seem to match up

Comment: You're right - I end up getting most of the values I want but for example, I'm missing the third row of A[1,] - B[3,] from my array...and get different values:  `head(diffs.so) -> -3 -1 -4 -2 -2 0` and `head(dia_outer) -> -3 -1 -4 -2 -5 -3` Thanks for catching that!!

Answer (score 0):

My solution: use nested lapply and sapply functions to extract the diagonals. I then needed to do some post-processing (not related to this specific problem), before I then turned it into an array. Should be noted that this is a q x 2 x n array, which turned out to be better for my purposes - this could be permuted with `aperm` from here though to solve the original question.

```
A <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
B <- matrix(4:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)

diffs <- outer(A,B, FUN = '-')
diffs <- lapply(X = 1:nrow(A),FUN = function(y){
    t(sapply(1:ncol(B), FUN = function(x) diag(diffs[y,,x,])))})


diffs <- array(unlist(lapply(diffs, FUN = t)), dim = c(nrow(B),2,nrow(A)))
```

Comment: This isn't quite reproducible. The values of `n`, `qt`, `q` and `X` can be surmised, but better would be for you to supply them up front. The idea is that one should be able to copy/paste the code into ones editor and have it run exactly as it did on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I'm hoping the edit I made just fulfilled your request.